# Bootstrap.js conflicts with require.js and disables Navbar dropdown

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, requirejs

I am working on a Django site, so I have a `base.html` with all my common stuff and extend it to the pages I need

Common scripts that are used by the entire site are in my `base.html`:

```
<script src="/static/js/libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/libs/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/libs/bs3/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My `dashboard.html` extends `base.html` , I am using `require.js` **only** for the `dashboard.html` and it includes the following at the very bottom:

```
<script data-main="/static/js/dashboard/main" src="/static/js/libs/require/require.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

My `main.js`

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': '../libs/jquery/jquery.min',

        // NOTE 1
        //'bootstrap': '../libs/bs3/bootstrap.min',

        // Backbone JS & Co
        "underscore": '../libs/underscore/underscore-min',
        "backbone": '../libs/backbone/backbone-min',

        // Dashboard Chart
        "salesView": 'views/Sales/DailySalesView',
    },
});

// Load Dashboard elements
require(["jquery", "underscore", "backbone", "salesView"], function ($, _, Backbone, SalesView) {

    // Show modal when dashboard page loads
    $('#loading-modal').modal('toggle');

}, function (err) {
    console.log(err)
});
```

**NOTE 1:**

When I have `bootstrap` ENABLED in my `main.js`, the modal loads fine, BUT the top Navbar dropdown `ul.nav > li.dropdown` stops working.

So I DISABLED `bootstrap` in my `main.js`, since `bootstrap.js` is already added in my `base.html`. Top Navbar dropdown works now BUT I get the following error

```
TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
```

**Q:** Since `bootstrap.js` is already added in my `base.html`, I am assuming it's already loaded and the `main.js` should be having access to it. Why isn't it the case? How do I solve this ?

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading jQuery with a `script` tag and loading it with RequireJS. This is a recipe for confusion. what happens is that Bootstrap is installed on the jQuery that is loaded with `script` but not on the one that RequireJS loads.

One way to solve the problem is to remove `jquery` from your paths and instead add into your `main.js` a fake `jquery` module that just reuses the one loaded with `script`:

```
define('jquery', function () {
    return $; // Just return the jQuery loaded with `script`.
});
```

Add it after your call to `requirejs.config` but before your `require` call.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Adding the `define` bit solved this issue.